# Напишите функцию, меняющую все заглавные на строчные и наоборот

Tags: c, функции

Прошу помощи в понимании...

из строчных в заглавные так работает:

```
if ('a' <= *ch && *ch <= 'z')         
*ch += ('A' - 'a');         
putchar(*ch);
```

однако из заглавных в строчные так же не работает:

```
if ('A' <= *ch && *ch <= 'Z')         
*ch += ('a' - 'A');         
putchar(*ch);
```

но если иначе, то работает:

```
if (*ch >= 'A' && *ch <= 'Z')         
*ch += ('a' - 'A');         
putchar(*ch);
```

Голову уже сломал. Не могу понять, в чём разница между:

```
'A' <= *ch
```

и

```
*ch >= 'A'
```

Ведь по моей логике, это одно и то же.

Где тут изъян? Буду премного благодарен за науку.

Моя функция:

```
void char_register(char * ch, int fl){
    if(fl == 1)
    {
    if ('a' <= *ch && *ch <= 'z') 
        *ch += ('A' - 'a');
     }
    if(fl == 0)
       {
     if (*ch >= 'A' && *ch <= 'Z')              
         *ch += ('a' - 'A');
       }
}
```

Благодарю всех, кто пытался мне помочь. Я разобрался... конечно, удобства онлайн компиляторов неоспоримы, но пока не попытался скомпилировать код на живом железе, не мог понять ошибки. Вот код:

[ideone](https://ideone.com/7Z98Gx)

Функция не меняла и не выдавала ошибок. GCC же выдал мне следующее:

```
register.c: In function ‘main’:
register.c:25:24: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘char_register’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
      char_register(&c, &fl);
                        ^~~
register.c:4:39: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
     void char_register(char * ch, int fl){
                                   ~~~~^~
```

Компиляция проходила, исполняемый файл запускался, но так же, не менял регистры символов. После фиксинга:

```
char_register(&c, fl);
```

Получил счастье и пошёл я гулять!!!! ))))

Comment: А что, `toupper` и `tolower` использовать нельзя?...

Comment: Нельзя. Учу язык, а не библиотеку. Так они мне сказали... )))

Comment: Ну тогда что-то вы недоговариваете... https://ideone.com/9NrfFE - вот, работает в варианте `'A' <= *ch && *ch <= 'Z'`.

Comment: Наверное я ещё туп - НЕ РАБОТАЕТ у меня. ((( Посмотрите пожалуйста. К примеру в случае: y 1 функция должна бы переводить в Y :
https://ideone.com/7Z98Gx

Comment: Она так и делает: https://ideone.com/kc5E9m

Comment: А у меня же было вот так: char_register(&c, &fl); и поэтому не делала. Спасибо за помощь. Мне помогли вы и варнинги GCC. Хорошего выходного дня!

Comment: Такие сложные расчеты ;) По ASCII таблице видно, что разница между A(65) и a(97) в 32. A+32=a, a-32=A. С русскими буквами есть нюансы :)

Answer (score 0):

написал по вашему примеру на **C++** (работает и так 'A' <= *ch и так *ch >= 'A') по моему мнению все таки желательней писать *ch >= 'A'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void task(char word[100])
{
    for (int i = 0;i < strlen(word);++i)
    {
        if ('A' <= word[i] && word[i] <= 'Z')
            word[i] = word[i] - 'A' + 'a';
        else if ('a' <= word[i] && word[i] <= 'z')
        {
            word[i] = word[i] - 'a' + 'A';
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    char word[100];
    cin >> word;
    task(word);
    cout << word;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. Наверное у меня был баг на онлайн компиляторе на ресурсе обучения.